# How do you test a Backbone Marionnette method inside of onShow in Jasmine?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine, marionette

I'm trying to test a view in Backbone Marionette but the onShow() never gets called so I can't test a method that is being called in that method.

views/test.coffee

```
onShow: () ->
  debugger # this never happens when I run the Jasmine tests
  alert "HI"
```

spec/javascripts/views/test_spec.coffee

```
  describe 'a test', ->

    beforeEach ->
      @view  = new window.TestView
      @view.render()

    it "does something", ->
      # not important
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onShow()` generally only gets called when you show it inside a region. There a two options you have for testing.

**1) call `onShow` manually after render:**

```
@view.render();
@view.onShow();
```

**2) show the view inside a region:**

You can just make a new region inside your test file, just add a detached DOM element if you don't need to use the DOM, otherwise you can just make an element and put it in the DOM.

*Sidenote*** I don't know CoffeeScript, so the following might not be syntactically correct!*

```
beforeEach ->
    @view  = new window.TestView
    @testRegion = new Backbone.Marionette.Region({el: document.createElement('div')})
    @testRegion.show(@view)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also trigger onShow. Sorry no CoffeeScript.

```
view.triggerMethod("show");
```